# What is this navigation method called? And how can I implement it into WordPress/Divi Builder?

Tags: website-design, interface-design

I'm in the process of doing a reskin on my company's website. Hoping to include a navigation method similar to what's used on [Tesla's homepage](https://www.tesla.com/) on the left. I want it to be reactive to where the user is on the page, and have the labels of the menu be interactive to let the user navigate to that portion of the page.

What is this called? A reactive breadcrumb?

Is there a WP plugin of somesort that has this, or does DiviBuilder support it natively?

Comment: They are merely in-page, named, anchors which are positioned absolutely and then javascript is used to control the smooth scrolling (boomerang.js)

Comment: Scott, thanks for the help. I'll do some research to see if there are any WordPress tools that can help make this easier for me. Don't particularly want to code it all myself lol.